# Why does my React Dom render method not work?

Tags: reactjs, django, render, react-router-dom, react-dom

I'm building a React-Django application, and on my App component, I'm getting an issue on the final line with my `render(<App />, appDiv)`.
Please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I have the necessary modules imported, and this worked on my previous project. *I am aware that Function-based components are better, but I'm more experienced with Class-based.*

Error:

[image: Error]

Code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="center">
        <HomePage />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
render(<App />, appDiv);
```

Thanks,

DillonB07

TypeError expanded:

[image: Slightly more detailed error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
```

with

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
```

And use `ReactDOM.render` instead of just `render`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but I get the exact same error. I cleared my cache, and the issue was still there, so it wasn't leftover from last time.

Comment: Now that I am looking at it. The error is in the file react-router.js. Do you use react-router in your project. If yes could you update the question with the React Router code in your components?

Comment: I am using React Router, but my error is pointing specifically to the `render()` line. Also, that file shown in the error is a package file, not my code.

Comment: yes it is a package file, but the package where the error is is react-router. Where did you get that it's exactly the ` render(<App />, appDiv);`

Comment: I got that it's the `render()` from expanding the `TypeError` the other files are either package files or my code built by webpack. I've added a new screenshot to the end of the post. The only thing that is mine is `eval @App.js:24`. I don't have 24 lines, but the webpack-compiled version adds more lines for imports etc

Comment: The ReactDOM.render is all right, it looks like there is an error somewhere in your code. People are having the same issue as you when they use for example Context API. Could you please share the whole codebase

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've uploaded the entire thing to GitHub. It's not very complete, but everything JS related is in the `frontend` folder. https://github.com/dbarnes18/Portfolio/

Comment: Well now I see it. home-page.js, line 43. Instead of `<Route exact path="/" render={this.renderHomePage()} />` use `<Route exact path="/" component={this.renderHomePage()} />` that's where the render undefined was from. And also try removing () around the `this.renderHomePage` I am not sure if it will work ->  try `{this.renderHomePage}`

Comment: Thank you! I must've missed that in the error!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. And for future. In the error there was somewhere mentioned react-router. So try to look where you use those components